# Push notification work on Release build, yet not after uploading to TestFlight

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Building with scheme configuration Release, I manage to get Push Notification (I've generated prod and dev certificates).

But after releasing to TestFlight, not receiving pushes any more, same exact build.

Any idea?

I'm using Firebase FCM for push notification, do not think it has anything to do with this, since push do work when building Release from Xcode on device.

Answer (score 0):

This is so strange, I've just revoked distribution certificate on apple developers portal, re created certificate request and certificate, and now it works both on build release, and on TestFlight.